# Python TypeError: multiple arguments with functools.partial

Tags: python, function

I ran into an error when using `partial` from the `functools` library.

```
from functools import partial
def add(x,a,b):
    return x + 10*a + 100*b

add = partial(add, x=2, b=3)
print (add(4))
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: add() got multiple values for argument 'x'
```

I know that this can be fixed by bringing forward `a` to the first positional argument of `add` like:

```
def add(b,a,x):
    return x + 10*a + 100*b

add = partial(add, x=2, a=3)
print (add(4))
```

which correctly gives out: `432`

My question is whether there is a way to **keep the order** of **x,a,b** intact within the `add` function and altering the `partial` function to give out the correct result. This is important because something like the `add` function is used elsewhere and so it is important for me to keep the order in the original `add` function intact.

I don't want to use a keyword argument with the function like print `(add(a = 4))` because I want it as an input to a map function
For example I want to do something like this:
 `print (list(map(add,[1,2,3])))`
 `print (min([1,2,3], key = add)))`

Comment: Unfortunate that this was closed, but one solution is to do:
`_add = partial(lambda a, x, b: add(x, a, b), x=2, b=3)
print(list(map(_add, [1,2,3])))` observe the use of `_add` vs. `add` when reassigning.

Comment: @salparadise ah very clever use of the lambda function

Comment: @Imran Please mark the answer as correct

Comment: apologies @mrangry777 I had edited my question to something a bit different after you gave your answer but I changed the question far too late. I've ticked your answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to resolve you issue is to use keyword arguments with this function like so

`print (add(b=4))`

Because using it like this `print (add(4))` assigns it to first parameter which partial already defined so `x` is passed twice

**EDIT**

You can also use partial with positional arguments

like so:

```
from functools import partial


def add(x, a, b):
    return x + 10 * a + 100 * b


add = partial(add, 2, 3)
print(add(4))
```

The second solution is possible because `x` and `a` are the first two parameters. The approach with keyword arguments is used when you do not want define consecutive parameters starting from the first.

Comment: if I wanted to do this `print (list(map(add,[1,2,3])))` without changing the order how would it be possible?

Comment: @Imran I do not understand the question please elaborate